# Will there be significant overhead when accessing same data file using multitprocessing?

Tags: python, csv, multiprocessing

I have a large data file (csv) that a bunch of processes are reading at the same time, line for line. There doesn't seem to be too much overhead now (doing a single call of f in the code below is 600 seconds without threading, 700s with), however I am soon moving to a cpu with a lot more cores and hence a lot more processes accessing this file at the same time. How do these read only operations scale with multiprocessing? Can only a single process access the file at a time?

The code currently looks something like this

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
 with open('data.csv', 'r') as read_obj:
  reader = reader(read_obj)
  for row in reader:
   #do something

if __name__=="__main__":
 params = [.....]
 with Pool() as pool:
  for _ in pool.imap(f, params):
   #also do something
```

I tried a small scale experiment (3 cores), there was not a lot of overhead, don't know if it translates to larger scale.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*overhead*" here?  Please use [edit] to clarify your question.

Comment: if anything, it's probably more efficient to access the same file (than several), but you'll probably find out the most from a benchmark!

Comment: note that in your example, you don't divide up reading the file, but each reader reads it entirely - is that intentional?

Comment: Your OS almost certainly has a disk cache, so most of the processes will be accessing an in-memory cache, not the file itself.

Comment: @ti7 Yes I want each process to read the file in its entirety.

Comment: If each CPU is doing the same work, how does this end up being faster with more cores?

Comment: @chepner Are you saying the current csvreader method will read the entire csv into cache? I'm guessing that the different processes will not share this cache but instead create the same copy in different caches?

Comment: @NickODell for this example they are doing the same thing, in reality each call of f does a different analysis of the data present in 'data.csv' based on argument params.

Comment: The granularity of a file cache is usually measured in fixed-size 'blocks', rather than entire files. Your *program* may only request a few bytes in any given read, but this will still result in an entire block being read from disk if necessary. All future reads from that block will be served from cache as long as the block is in the cache, regardless of which bytes from that block are requested.

Comment: (A typical block size is, I think, around 4 KB, so actual peformance will depend on how much each process tries to read from the same area of a file as other processes, as well as how many blocks the cache can hold. A 4MB cache, for instance, can hold 1000 4KB blocks at a time. Once the cache fills, blocks are ejected as room is needed for new blocks read from disk.)

Comment: @BHK In that example, reading and parsing the file is overhead. You would only need to do it once in a single-threaded program, and you're doing it multiple times because it's a multi-threaded program. It may be the fastest way to do it, but it's still overhead.

Comment: @chepner Worth mentioning: 1) the page cache is shared between all processes, and 2) the cache is usually gigabytes in size, since unused memory is used for the page cache.